# How to unwind single document and then process into single result in an array

Tags: json, mongodb, report

I have had some great help from @Joao and @Blakes Seven in order to get me as far as I've got. Awesome, thanks guys very much.
What I have a problem with is going from my original simple example and applying it to my real life scenario.

Where I've got to is two separate scripts which work perfectly by themselves but when I try to being the two together, it then only does the first part without applying the second part; it's my lack of experience in Mongo letting me down here.

So, I am able to get a name value pair from the first array set within a document using the following code:

```
db.raw_originBusinessData.aggregate([
{ "$match": {objectOriginAPI : "Profit & Loss"}}
,{ "$unwind": "$objectRawOriginData.Reports" }
,{ "$unwind": "$objectRawOriginData.Reports.Rows" }
,{ "$unwind": "$objectRawOriginData.Reports.Rows.Rows" }
,{ "$group": {"_id": "$_id","first": { "$first": "$objectRawOriginData.Reports.Rows.Rows.Cells.Value" }
,   "temp": { "$push": "$objectRawOriginData.Reports.Rows.Rows.Cells.Value" }
}},
{ "$unwind": "$temp" }
,{"$skip":1}
,{ "$group": {"_id": "$_id", "AccountBalance":{ "$first": "$first" }
}}
])
```

This gives me the result below, which I'm happy with except for the fact I am not able to name the two values in the Account Balances array.

**Mission 1**: I want AccountBalance to be an array and the first position has two values: "AccountName" : "Sales", "AccountValue" : 5428.04.

```
{
"result" : [ 
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("564d12da1506995581569428"),
        "AccountBalance" : [ 
            "Sales", 
            "5428.64"
        ]
    }
],
"ok" : 1.0000000000000000
}
```

The second part of the problem is that it is only processing one set of values whereas, the document I am processing on has 9 sets to do. I have run the following $unwind on the document and it has perfectly split them into 9 results:

```
db.raw_originBusinessData.aggregate([
// find document
{ "$match": {objectOriginAPI : "Profit & Loss"}}

// unwind into multiple documents
,{ "$unwind": "$objectRawOriginData.Reports" }
,{ "$unwind": "$objectRawOriginData.Reports.Rows" }
,{ "$unwind": "$objectRawOriginData.Reports.Rows.Rows" }
])
```

So I get 9 results perfect. **Mission 2:** What I want to do is to combine this with the script I showed above. I tried the following but it does absolutely no more than the script just above.

```
db.raw_originBusinessData.aggregate([
// find document
{ "$match": {objectOriginAPI : "Profit & Loss"}}

// unwind into multiple documents
,{ "$unwind": "$objectRawOriginData.Reports" }
,{ "$unwind": "$objectRawOriginData.Reports.Rows" }
,{ "$unwind": "$objectRawOriginData.Reports.Rows.Rows" }
]
// process each document
,{ "$unwind": "$objectRawOriginData.Reports" }
, {"$unwind": "$objectRawOriginData.Reports.Rows" }
, {"$unwind": "$objectRawOriginData.Reports.Rows.Rows" }
, {"$group": {"_id": "$_id","first": { "$first": "$objectRawOriginData.Reports.Rows.Rows.Cells.Value" }
,   "a": { "$push": "$objectRawOriginData.Reports.Rows.Rows.Cells.Value" }
}},
{ "$unwind": "$a" }
,{"$skip":1}
,{ "$group": {"_id": "$_id", "AccountBalance":{ "$first": "$first" }
}}  
)
```

**Desired Outcome**

What I want to get is the following. This is combination of mission 1 and 2.

```
{
"result" : [ 
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("564d12da1506995581569428"),
        "AccountBalance" : [ 
            {"AccountName" : "Sales", 
            "AccountValue" : "5428.64"},
            {"AccountName" : "Total Income", 
            "AccountValue" : "5428.64"},
            {"AccountName" : "Cost of Sales", 
            "AccountValue" : "100.00"},
            {"AccountName" : "Total Cost of Sales", 
            "AccountValue" : "100.00"},
            {"AccountName" : "Gross Profit", 
            "AccountValue" : "5328.64"},
            {"AccountName" : "Advertising", 
            "AccountValue" : "100.00"},
            {"AccountName" : "General Expenses", 
            "AccountValue" : "100.00"},
            {"AccountName" : "Total Operating Expenses", 
            "AccountValue" : "200.00"},
            {"AccountName" : "Net Profit", 
            "AccountValue" : "5128.64"}
        ]
    }
],
"ok" : 1.0000000000000000
}
```

The document that I am using as a source is from Xero API - it's one of their reports. It has the same pattern as most reports exported in JSON like Oracle. Below is the actual report so that you have it for reference.

Thanks a million guys, very much appreciated!

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("564d12da1506995581569428"),
"objectClass" : "Origin Data",
"objectCategory" : "Application",
"objectType" : "Customer",
"connection_id" : "562033dfca91840cd0c7c54f",
"connectionName" : "Building Accounts",
"entity_id" : "564149bcca9183a8d0c7c83c",
"objectCreationDate" : "2015-11-19 14:43:40",
"objectCycleID" : "12345678",
"objectStatus" : "PROCESSED",
"objectOrigin" : "Xero",
"objectOriginAPI" : "Profit & Loss",
"objectOriginService" : "Xero API - Profit & Loss v 1.0.0.8",
"objectRawOriginData" : {
    "Id" : "d6e7fb37-9f2e-45ae-b0a4-de62aa95a783",
    "Status" : "OK",
    "ProviderName" : "Xero API Previewer",
    "DateTimeUTC" : "/Date(1443405874333)/",
    "Reports" : [ 
        {
            "ReportID" : "ProfitAndLoss",
            "ReportName" : "Profit and Loss",
            "ReportType" : "ProfitAndLoss",
            "ReportTitles" : [ 
                "Profit & Loss", 
                "Paddy's markets", 
                "28 September 2014 to 28 September 2015"
            ],
            "ReportDate" : "28 September 2015",
            "UpdatedDateUTC" : "/Date(1443405874333)/",
            "Fields" : [],
            "Rows" : [ 
                {
                    "RowType" : "Header",
                    "Cells" : [ 
                        {
                            "Value" : ""
                        }, 
                        {
                            "Value" : "28 Sep 15"
                        }
                    ]
                }, 
                {
                    "RowType" : "Section",
                    "Title" : "Income",
                    "Rows" : [ 
                        {
                            "RowType" : "Row",
                            "Cells" : [ 
                                {
                                    "Value" : "Sales",
                                    "Attributes" : [ 
                                        {
                                            "Value" : "a7e3f9e4-6f63-4b25-ae36-107131e8b9be",
                                            "Id" : "account"
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }, 
                                {
                                    "Value" : "5428.64",
                                    "Attributes" : [ 
                                        {
                                            "Value" : "a7e3f9e4-6f63-4b25-ae36-107131e8b9be",
                                            "Id" : "account"
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            ]
                        }, 
                        {
                            "RowType" : "SummaryRow",
                            "Cells" : [ 
                                {
                                    "Value" : "Total Income"
                                }, 
                                {
                                    "Value" : "5428.64"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }, 
                {
                    "RowType" : "Section",
                    "Title" : "Less Cost of Sales",
                    "Rows" : [ 
                        {
                            "RowType" : "Row",
                            "Cells" : [ 
                                {
                                    "Value" : "Cost of Sales",
                                    "Attributes" : [ 
                                        {
                                            "Value" : "f78f7118-ad98-4862-a63c-39dd3c5ace8a",
                                            "Id" : "account"
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }, 
                                {
                                    "Value" : "100.00",
                                    "Attributes" : [ 
                                        {
                                            "Value" : "f78f7118-ad98-4862-a63c-39dd3c5ace8a",
                                            "Id" : "account"
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            ]
                        }, 
                        {
                            "RowType" : "SummaryRow",
                            "Cells" : [ 
                                {
                                    "Value" : "Total Cost of Sales"
                                }, 
                                {
                                    "Value" : "100.00"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }, 
                {
                    "RowType" : "Section",
                    "Title" : "",
                    "Rows" : [ 
                        {
                            "RowType" : "Row",
                            "Cells" : [ 
                                {
                                    "Value" : "Gross Profit"
                                }, 
                                {
                                    "Value" : "5328.64"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }, 
                {
                    "RowType" : "Section",
                    "Title" : "Less Operating Expenses",
                    "Rows" : [ 
                        {
                            "RowType" : "Row",
                            "Cells" : [ 
                                {
                                    "Value" : "Advertising",
                                    "Attributes" : [ 
                                        {
                                            "Value" : "67466588-132b-48ce-b897-0ceabffd7a9d",
                                            "Id" : "account"
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }, 
                                {
                                    "Value" : "100.00",
                                    "Attributes" : [ 
                                        {
                                            "Value" : "67466588-132b-48ce-b897-0ceabffd7a9d",
                                            "Id" : "account"
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            ]
                        }, 
                        {
                            "RowType" : "Row",
                            "Cells" : [ 
                                {
                                    "Value" : "General Expenses",
                                    "Attributes" : [ 
                                        {
                                            "Value" : "fdb25d7a-2fc8-406a-bf4b-6b4e8014b8cb",
                                            "Id" : "account"
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }, 
                                {
                                    "Value" : "100.00",
                                    "Attributes" : [ 
                                        {
                                            "Value" : "fdb25d7a-2fc8-406a-bf4b-6b4e8014b8cb",
                                            "Id" : "account"
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            ]
                        }, 
                        {
                            "RowType" : "SummaryRow",
                            "Cells" : [ 
                                {
                                    "Value" : "Total Operating Expenses"
                                }, 
                                {
                                    "Value" : "200.00"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }, 
                {
                    "RowType" : "Section",
                    "Title" : "",
                    "Rows" : [ 
                        {
                            "RowType" : "Row",
                            "Cells" : [ 
                                {
                                    "Value" : "Net Profit"
                                }, 
                                {
                                    "Value" : "5128.64"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

done it, see below, thanks:

```
db.raw_originBusinessData.aggregate([
{ "$match": {objectOriginAPI : "Profit & Loss"}}
,{ "$unwind": "$objectRawOriginData.Reports" }
,{ "$unwind": "$objectRawOriginData.Reports.Rows" }
,{ "$unwind": "$objectRawOriginData.Reports.Rows.Rows" }
,{ "$group": {"_id": "$_id","accountBalances": { "$push": "$objectRawOriginData.Reports.Rows.Rows.Cells.Value" }
}},
])
```